How to use WhastsApp API to send messages to my user's customers?
I'm developing an app for sending WhatsApp notifications.
Can users of my app send automated notifications to their customers through WhatsApp?
Here (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/guides/send-messages#) in the documentation it doesn't say I am not allowed, but when I try to use it from my customer's list, it says they're not registered in my WhatsApp API app list.
My user should be able to click in the "send notification" button and it should send to their selected customer number.
But WhtsApp returns an error informing that the number is not registered in my WhatsApp API setup.
Also, this is was not accepting the template message:
patientPhoneNumber
export const sendAppointmentNotification = async (
  req: Request,
  res: Response,
  next: NextFunction
): Promise<void> => {
  try {
    const { id: patientId } = req.params;

    if (!patientId) {
      res.status(400).json({ message: 'Patient Id is required' });
    }

    const userRequest = req.session;

    if (!userRequest.user) {
      res.status(403).json({ message: 'User not authenticated' });
      return;
    }

    const therapist = userRequest.user as ITherapist;

    const foundPatient = therapist.patients?.find(
      (p) => p.toString() === patientId
    );
    const patient = await Patient.findById(foundPatient);

    if (!patient) {
      res
        .status(400)
        .json({ message: 'Not possible to locate this Patient by this ID' });
      return;
    }

    const patientPhoneNumber = patient.contacts.phone;

    if (!patientPhoneNumber) {
      res.status(400).json({ message: 'Patient does not have a phone number' });
      return;
    }

    const templateMessage = getTemplateMessageInput(
      APPOINTMENT_NOTIFICATION,
      'pt_BR'
    );

    const messageData = {
      messaging_product: 'whatsapp',
      to: patientPhoneNumber,
      type: 'template',
      template: {
        name: 'appointment_notification',
        language: {
          code: 'pt_BR',
        },
        components: [
          {
            type: 'body',
            parameters: [
              {
                type: 'text',
                text: 'FirstParameter',
              },
              {
                type: 'text',
                text: 'SecondParameter',
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    };

    await sendWppMessage(messageData);
    res
      .status(200)
      .json({ message: 'Appointment notification sent successfully' });
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
};


Just found that this is not possible to be done via WhatsApp API cloud.
